# strictly concave function whose third derivative is negative?

Tags: functions

Consider a continuous function $u(q)\geq 0$ whose domain is $[0,\infty)$ that satisfies the following conditions:

1. $u^{\prime }>0$ for all $q \in [0,\infty)$,
2. $u^{\prime \prime }<0$ for all $q \in [0,\infty)$,
3. $u(0)=0$,
4. $u^{\prime }(0)<\infty $

Now I am wondering whether $\frac{u^{\prime \prime }(q)}{u^{\prime }(q)}$ is weakly increasing in $q$ always hold ? Is there any function $u(q)$ making $\frac{u^{\prime \prime }(q)}{u^{\prime }(q)}$decreasing in $q$ or non-monotonic in $q$?

Here is what I have done:
$\frac{d\Big(\frac{u^{\prime \prime }(q)}{u^{\prime }(q)}\Big)}{d q}=\frac{u^{\prime \prime \prime}(q)u^{\prime}(q)-[u^{\prime \prime}(q)]^{2}}{[u^{\prime}(q)]^{2}}$. So if $u^{\prime \prime \prime}(q)<0$ or $u^{\prime \prime \prime}(q)u^{\prime}(q)<[u^{\prime \prime}(q)]^{2}$ holds for some $q$, I can conclude the above conjecture is not true. But I cannot figure out a such a function. Can you help to find out such a function? thank you !

Comment: It's not possible that $u'''(q)<0$ for all $q$, as this would imply $u'(q)\leq u'(1)+u''(1)(q-1)$ for $q>1$, so $u'(q)\rightarrow-\infty$ as $q\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: thank you. But is it possible that $u^{\prime \prime \prime}(q)<0$ for some $q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{u''}{u'}$ can equal any continuous function $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow(-\infty,0)$. In particular it can be increasing, decreasing or neither.

Indeed let
$$
  G(q)=\int_0^qg(t)\;dt,
$$
$$
  u(q)=\int_0^qe^{G(t)}\;dt.
$$
Then $u(0)=0$, $u'=e^G>0$, $u''=ge^G<0$, $u'(0)=e^{G(0)}=1$ and $\frac{u''}{u'}=g$.

Comment: great work ! Thank you so much !